# Swift framework imported into Objc-C binary does not generate Obj-c header correctly, missed @import Cocoa;

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, compiler-errors

I am building a Mac OS X app (binary). Skit is the Swift framework, and Pal is the Application which contains the .m file. The compiler cannot find NSArray or NSDictionary, which means that the compiler can't find the Foundation module. If I go to the error in Pal-Swift.h (which is generated) and add the @import Foundation or @import Cocoa manually, the binary compiles fine and I am able to use the classes in the framework from objc as expected, and I can typically keep iterating until I need to do a clean build.

The error looks like this.

```
    While building module 'SKit' imported from /Users/mtozer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pal-dznqzplhixgqpgduvvxjqiknvhrr/Build/Intermediates/Pal.build/Debug/Pal.build/DerivedSources/Pal-Swift.h:90:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Users/mtozer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pal-dznqzplhixgqpgduvvxjqiknvhrr/Build/Products/Debug/SPluginKit.framework/Headers/SKit-Swift.h:97:26: error: expected a type
- (void)executeCommands:(NSArray * __nonnull)commands;
                         ^
/Users/mtozer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pal-dznqzplhixgqpgduvvxjqiknvhrr/Build/Products/Debug/SKit.framework/Headers/SKit-Swift.h:115:4: error: expected a type
+ (NSDictionary<NSString *, id <SPlugin>> * __nonnull)loadPluginsInDirectory:(NSString * __nonnull)directory sAPI:(id <SAPI> __nonnull)sAPI;
   ^
2 errors generated.
In file included from /Users/mtozer/Pal/Pal/AppDelegate.m:43:
/Users/mtozer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pal-dznqzplhixgqpgduvvxjqiknvhrr/Build/Intermediates/Pal.build/Debug/Pal.build/DerivedSources/Pal-Swift.h:90:9: fatal error: could not build module 'SKit'
@import SKit;
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly convinced this is a compiler bug, but then again I am using BUCK which does not officially support swift.

Simply putting an empty extension in my Framework's source code caused the generator to put the foundation dependency correctly in the header

```
extension NSArray {

}
```

Comment: I'm not using (and am unfamiliar with BUCK), but I randomly had the same problem crop up out of nowhere.  No idea how you figured this out, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remember to prepend @objc to the classes and protocols declaration in Swift.

```
@objc public class YourClassName: NSObject { ... }

@objc public protocol YourProtocolName { ... }
```

If the problem persists then try appending `: class` at the end of the protocols used as Swift protocols can be implemented not only by classes as happens in Objc.

```
@objc public protocol YourProtocolName: class { ... }
```